# How do I filter an array based on the values of one of its nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter

Say I have an array of objects that follows the pattern below:

```
var posts = [
    {
        title: post_ab,
        category_array : [
            { id: 1, slug: category-a },
            { id: 2, slug: category-b }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: post_ac,
        category_array : [
            { id: 1, slug: category-a },
            { id: 3, slug: category-c }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: post_bc,
        category_array : [
            { id: 2, slug: category-b },
            { id: 3, slug: category-c }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to filter the above array, and only return values where the category_array contains a slug matching a specified value.

For example, if I wanted to filter against 'category-c', only the 2nd and 3rd values (post_ac and post_bc) would be returned.

I've tried with nested filters, which is getting me nowhere:

```
var currentCategory = 'category-b';

var filteredPosts = function( posts ) {
    return posts.filter( function( post ){
        return post.category_array.filter( function( category ){
            return category.slug === currentCategory;
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Change that inner filter to [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control), e.g. `post.category_array.some` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in the inner loop:

```
var filteredPosts = function(posts) {
    return posts.filter(function(post){
        return post["category_array"].some(function(category){
            return category.slug === currentCategory;
        });
    });
}
```

It will return a `boolean` result that can be used in the `.filter()` callback.

Comment: Nailed it - thank you. Although the above example gives a syntax error (my fault for not wrapping the titles in quotes).

Comment: You are welcome. Yes it is an error in the JS array.

Comment: Accepted as it sticks to my antiquated JS syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Let's combine [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example) with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)

```js
var posts = [
        {
            title: 'post_ab',
            category_array : [
                { id: 1, slug: 'category-a' },
                { id: 2, slug: 'category-b' }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'post_ac',
            category_array : [
                { id: 1, slug: 'category-a' },
                { id: 3, slug: 'category-c' }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'post_bc',
            category_array : [
                { id: 2, slug: 'category-b' },
                { id: 3, slug: 'category-c' }
            ]
        }
    ];
    var result = posts.filter(a => a.category_array.some(cat => cat.slug.includes('a')));
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Using arrow functions renders those `return` statements a bit redundant. `posts.filter(a => a.category_array.some(cat => cat.slug.includes('a')))`. Otherwise, looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.some

```
posts.filter(
  (elem) => (
    elem.category_array.some(
      elem => elem.slug === currentCategory;
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get first element with `slug` equal to `'category-b'` in the array `category_array` and returning that element if exists will be evaluated as truthy, or falsey if not exist, by the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var posts = [{title: 'post_ab',category_array : [{ id: 1, slug: 'category-a' },{ id: 2, slug: 'category-b' }]},{title: 'post_ac',category_array : [{ id: 1, slug: 'category-a' },{ id: 3, slug: 'category-c' }]},{title: 'post_bc',category_array : [{ id: 2, slug: 'category-b' },{ id: 3, slug: 'category-c' }]}],
    currentCategory = 'category-b',
    result = posts.filter(function (p) {
      // Return only the very first element found
      return p.category_array.find(function (c) {
        return currentCategory === c.slug;
      });
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks - definitely more in-line with my approach - but the use of Array.some in a few of the other answers is a bit more elegant, IMO.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I didn't either up/downvote, and it probably doesn't matter for small datasets, but `filter`ing twice will iterate both datasets twice when there is no need. `some`, [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control), [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) would all only iterate until the match was found.

Comment: @CodingIntrigue it is performance because another filter will iterate over all the array.. Agree!. Now updated the answer to use `Array.prototype.find()` that will return the very first element found.. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score -2):

Replace your inner filter with some()